# Call 'Large' ref, grab value from column in referenced row

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a few columns, five for example. Multiple rows. For each individual row, on column A and B, I have two strings that I would like to reference. Columns C and D add up into column E, which totals the two values.

What I'm looking to do is reference the largest values in the chart, pull that number, and also return the two strings in columns A and B.

I know you can pull the largest number in range x,y in col E with =LARGE(Ex:Ey,1), but how does one reference the row that the number represents?

Let's say for reference that the two strings in the sixth row are `Alpha` and `Bravo`, and this sixth row contains the largest value (`26` for example) that I want to pull.

I'm looking for a way to get the output `26 Alpha Bravo`, if that's possible. I'm making a list going from largest to smallest, so I'm looking for a way to incorporate LARGE in there as well - looking to pick the 10 largest values and their respective strings.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to get the output 26 Alpha Bravo, if that's possible.

Please try:

```
=MAX(E:E)&" "&INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(E:E),E:E,0))&" "&INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(E:E),E:E,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try =MATCH(LARGE(A1:A6, 2),A1:A6,0)
Large returns the value you are looking for, and match will find the row it is in. Use the row starting in row 1 for match to give you the physical row, not the instance within the list.   Match with the third argument set to zero is basically a find first, and the Match function can also accept wildcards.